# Node.js Ajax error POST 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax to get the data from the controller on the client-side every 5 seconds. but turn out I got an error instead.

Here this is my controller

```
queue2: function(req, res){
    var mac = req.param('mac');
    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
 req.connection.remoteAddress || 
 req.socket.remoteAddress ||
 (req.connection.socket ? req.connection.socket.remoteAddress : null);

     dns.lookup(ip,function onLookup(err, addresses){

         console.log('Address :' + addresses);

     dns.reverse(addresses, function(err, hostname){


     knex.raw("CALL GetQueuePlay('00');")
     .then(function(result){

        var number = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0][0]));
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0][0])))
        return res.view('kue/kue',{q_play_list:number});


      })


        });
    });

},
```

this is on the client-side

```
function fetchdata(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '127.0.0.1/queue', //where my route is. 
        data: ({ QNum : 0 , station_num: 0 }),
        success: function(result){
            console.log('Data Appeared!' + result);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown) {
            console.log("something is wrong: " + textStatus + errorThrown);
        }

    });

}       

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(fetchdata, 5000);
});
```

And the error on the console show `"POST http://localhost/queue 404 (Not Found)"`

I assume that data have not get through or something but I have no idea what's wrong with this.

Thanks!

Comment: does the server run on port 80? Other requests work correctly?

Comment: @Saeed.At Yes, and other requests work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a 404 not found error try changing the URL to `/queue` such as:

```
function fetchdata(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/queue', //where my route is. 
        data: ({ QNum : 0 , station_num: 0 }),
        success: function(result){
            console.log('Data Appeared!' + result);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown) {
            console.log("something is wrong: " + textStatus + errorThrown);
        }

    });

}       

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(fetchdata, 5000);
});
```

Otherwise the URL is a relative URL treating 127.0.0.1 as a directory.

Answer (score 0):

404 means you don't have a post route for `queue`.

I think you do not have the route for `queue` or something is wrong with it.

```
router.post('/queue', function(req, res) {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: I'm using sails.js, does this require post router too?

Comment: I did not work with `sail.js`. but 404 means there is a problem with that route. read documents and check that again.@Max13